# Table width 100% but don't want to stretch central cell

Tags: html, css

I have the following table which has a central image holding cell which spans two rows:

```
<table width="100%" style="text-align:center">
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td rowspan="2"><img src="http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg"/></td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 5</td>
    <td>Cell 6</td>
    <td>Cell 7</td>
    <td>Cell 8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want the table and all the cells without the image in to fill the maximum amount of space available but I want the image cells width to adjust to only take up the space required by the image. I assume this is one of those scenarios where you use clever margin - values to achieve the effect but I can't quite figure out how to do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/7eX4S/

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a width of `25%` for the other four columns and use `width: auto;` for the central column:

```css
td {
    width: 25%; }

td[rowspan] {
    width: auto; }
```

Or use CSS3 [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) pseudo-class instead:

```css
td:not([rowspan]) {
    width: 25%; }
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/7eX4S/1/)**

Answer (score 5):

You can simply assign an inline width attribute of a too small value (for example `width="1px"`) and the container will size up to fit the image.

```
<td rowspan="2" width="1px"><img src="http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg"/></td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KRL9v/

Comment: +1 , `<td>` adjust to their content, they can expand and shrink if no `table-layout` set to `fixed` :)